# What does "fastmod" means in mongodb logs

Tags: mongodb

I have thought fastmod specifies some operations like update-in-place. 
In my app I'm doing update by _id using '$' modifiers, for example:

```
$colleciton->update(
    array('_id' => $id),
    array(
        '$inc' => array('hits' => new MongoInt32(1)),
        '$set' => array(
                      'times.gen' => gettimeofday(true),
                      'http.code' => new MongoInt32(200)
         )
    ),
    array('safe'=>false,'multiple'=>false,'upsert'=>false)
);
```

I've got such logs:

```
Wed Jul 25 11:08:36 [conn7002912] update mob.stat_pages query: { _id: BinData } update: { $inc: { hits: 1 }, $set: { times.gen: 1343203715.684896, http.code: 200 } } nscanned:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:342973 342ms
```

In logs as you can see I don't have any "fastmod" flags. There is no "moved" flag, because I set fields 'times.gen' and 'http.code' on insert, so padding factor is 1.0.

Am I doing something wrong, or I misunderstood meaning of fastmod?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the source code?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm not sure it would help me. I'm not so skilled :(

Comment: But why do you want to know that? It seems a pretty advanced knowledge to me. :)

Comment: I have high percentage of lock writes, so I'm trying to optimize my app somehow. I saw fastmod updates earlier but now it's gone and I don't know why.

Comment: High `%locked` usually means that your working set is larger than RAM and mongodb has to constantly read/write memory pages from/to disk. Even with an in-place update, if the memory page was on disk, you'll run into troubles.

Comment: in mongostat I have 0 "faults" all time.

Comment: Or actually it's totally possible. How many writes/sec do you do?

Comment: Average 45, from 20 to 55 depend on time of day. http://s017.radikal.ru/i421/1207/95/672cc8a4d831.png

Comment: Updates are writes as well. Are you running with journaling? What disks are you on?

Comment: journaling is turning on. SAS disk, filesystem EXT4. 16GB RAM.

Comment: have you confirmed that the fields you are setting and incrementing exist for the logged non-fastmod operations?

Comment: if they wasn't exist we'd see "moved" flag, because document grow. And on insert I'm setting this fields as hits=MongoInt32(1), times.gen=0.0, http.code=MongoInt32(0)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that "fastmod" in the logs means an in-place update.  Some possible reasons for the omission of logged fastmod/in-place operations:

1. You are actually setting or incrementing a field that doesn't exist, so it must be added, not an in place operation
2. The logs only show slow queries (default >100ms), so the in-place ones are probably happening too fast to be logged
3. You seem to be using 2.1 or 2.2 judging by the log - did the messages disappear if/when you switched to the new version?

In terms of looking into this further:

Have a look at [the profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-EnablingProfiling), try with different settings, note: profiling adds load - so use carefully.

You can also try setting the slowms value lower, either on start up or:

```
> db.setProfilingLevel(0,20) // slow threshold=20ms
```

Comment: Yes, I am using _version: 2.2.0-rc0_ and I saw fastmod updates in the log earlier on the same version. I will try to setProfilingLevel(2) for few minutes and then check are there any fastmod updates.

Comment: Ok. I tried. When I setProfilingLevel to 1 or 2, fastmod flag appears in log (sometimes they are not realy fast ^_^, but they are exists. Longest I saw was about 0.4 sec) But when I setProfilingLevel to 0, "fastmod" flag disappears from log. Is it OK?

Comment: Yep - it means that any time (or at least most of the time) you hit a fastmod and are doing an in-place update, it's under the threshold of 100ms for a default slow operation to be logged.  When the update can't be done in place (maybe field doesn't exist for example), then it is slower, not a fastmod and breaks the 100ms threshold, hence gets logged - make sense?

Comment: ok, it's difficult to explain because of my english, but I'll try, sry.. Let's forget about setProfililngLevel(2) when we write all operations to log. Let's do setProfilingLevel(1,50) and then "show log global": I see alot of "fastmod:1", I'd even say that all updates are fastmod. Then we do setProfilingLevel(0,50) and again "show log global": we don't see any "fastmod:1". It looks like some kind of loging problem, isn't it?

Comment: when you set the profiling level to 0, the profiler is off, you will only see any slow ops in the mongod log.  When you set it to 1 the profiler will log anything that breaks the threshold (in your case 50ms), when you set it to 2 it will log everything.  Unless I am misunderstanding I think that is the way it is supposed to be.  If it is not, and you think you have a bug with logging or the profiler, then head over to http://jira.mongodb.org and log it against the 2.2-rc0 version (with example output and log preferably)  so we can fix it :)

Comment: thank you for answers. And the last time I disturb you. While I was analizing logs I found a record: http://g.ua/CUyq . Why **nscanned:2** while I queried by "_id", is it because of additional criteria? And one more screen http://g.ua/CUyz the same query, but **nscanned:1**. Difference that in first case document by this id already had **times.i2** set in non-zero value. In the second case it was equal 0.

Comment: Probably the nscanned 1 examined just the index (1) while the nscanned 2 hit the index and the document itself - the both apply for that counter